# nginxで複数のWebアプリケーションのアクセスをパスで振り分けたい

Tags: nginx

アクセスさせたいWebアプリケーションが3つあります。

1. アプリ名：a-appli、アクセスパス：`http://localhost:9000/`
2. アプリ名：b-appli、アクセスパス：`http://localhost:8080/`
3. アプリ名：c-appli、アクセスパス：`http://localhost:8000/`

それを、nginxを用い、それぞれ

1. a-appli は `http://localhost/a-appli/`
2. b-appli は `http://localhost/b-appli/`
3. c-appli は `http://localhost/c-appli/`

という風なアクセスをさせたい場合にどのようにconfを書けば良いでしょうか？

いずれのアプリも

```
http://localhost:9000/hogehoge/hoge?a=x&c=d
```

のような場合は、

```
http://localhost/a-appli/hogehoge/hoge?a=x&c=d
```

でアクセス出来る様にさせたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

凝ったことヌキの教科書通りの回答ですが、、

```
upstream a-appli {
  server  127.0.0.1:9000;
}
upstream b-appli {
  server  127.0.0.1:8080;
}
upstream c-appli {
  server  127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

としておいて、 `server{...}` の中で、、

```
location /a-appli {
  rewrite ^/(.+) $1 break;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://a-appli/$1$is_args$args;
}
location /b-appli {
  rewrite ^/(.+) $1 break;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://b-appli/$1$is_args$args;
}
location /c-appli {
  rewrite ^/(.+) $1 break;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://c-appli/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

とかでしょうか。。

諸々の調整なんかは公式のドキュメントなどを参照してくださいませ。

Comment: ありがとうございました！正規表現の書き方部分などとても参考なりました。